# ¿Como hago para mostrar el nombre y apellido del usuario logeado una vez iniciada la sesion?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, login

Dentro la tabla que contiene los usuarios, tengo campos como ID, Apellidos, Nombres, Rol, Usuario, Password.
Lo que quiero es que despues de logear me muestre los datos del usuario logeado.

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PARA EL FORMULARIO

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#entrarSistema').click(function(){
            if($('#usuario').val()==""){
                alertify.alert("Debes agregar el usuario");
                return false;
            }else if($('#password').val()==""){
                alertify.alert("Debes agregar el password");
                return false;
            }
            cadena="usuario=" + $('#usuario').val() + 
                    "&password=" + $('#password').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"php/login.php",
                        data:cadena,
                        success:function(r){
                            if(r==1){
                                window.location="inicio.php";
                            }else{
                                alertify.alert("Fallo al entrar :(");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }); 

    });

</script>
```

Y ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO DEL LOGIN

```
<?php 


    session_start();
    require_once "conexion.php";

    $conexion=conexion();

        $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];
        
        $sql="SELECT * from Usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and password='$pass'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $_SESSION['user']=$usuario;
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
 ?>
```

Dentro la tabla que contiene los usuarios, tengo campos como ID, Apellidos, Nombres, Rol, Usuario, Password.
Lo que quiero es que despues de logear me muestre los datos del usuario logeado.

Comment: Donde almacenas tus variables de usuario, por ejemplo $_SESSION['user'] debes conocer el nombre de los campos para los demás campos que quieres mostrar y guardarlos en una variable por igual.

Answer (score 1):

Primero tendrías que hacer un `select` de tus datos.

```
$datos = mysqli_query( "SELECT / FROM / WHERE / = '/'");
```

Esto lo que hace es seleccionar los datos del usuario logueado gracias al `WHERE`, ya que eso significa `WHERE` el id sea igual al id del usuario logueado (aquí ya lo he visto en tu código, aquí `$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];` tu WHERE sería de `WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");`
Donde se encuentra esto / cámbialo por tus datos de la base de datos.
Aquí lo que estamos haciendo es mantener los datos que después tendrás que sostener con:

```
$hold = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos);
```

Luego tienes que utilizar $_SESSION, añadiendo esta línea `$_SESSION[''] = $hold[''];`con cada uno de los grupos que tienes, por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $hold['id'];
$_SESSION['Apellidos'] = $hold['Apellidos'];
$_SESSION['Rol'] = $hold['Rol'];
```

Así añadiendo en tu código `echo $hold['']` se mostrará o `<?php echo $hold[''] ?>` para `html` creo que no te tendría que dar ningún problema. Comenta si sale algún problema o tienes dudas.

Comment: Puedes ayudarme con el código exacto por favor, no entendí bien ya que soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Imagino que estos datos los guardas en una tabla, tienes algún campo que se rellene que sea único en cada usuario?

Comment: si, estoy mostrando el campo id en la tabla